# sFTP access issues on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, sftp

I've setup sFTP access on an Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic server but i'm having what i think are permission issues.

With the sFTP account i've created it logs in automatically to:

> /srv/www/domain.com/

However, i'm only actually able to upload to:

> /srv/www/domain.com/public_html

This is not workable as i need to create directories etc parallel to public_html. I appreciate this is something i've probably done wrong as its patched together from a few help files.

I followed [these instructions](http://library.linode.com/networking/security-guides/linux-sftp-jail) to create a group for sFTP access, i then created a user and then mod'ed their home directory using:

> usermod -d /srv/www/domain.com newuser

Let me know if there's any other information you need to troubleshoot this.

**OUTPUT OF COMMANDS**

```
> ls -al /srv/www/domain.com/ | grep public_html
drwxr-xr-x 2 newuser newuser 4096 2010-08-24 12:38 public_html

> ls -al /srv/www/ | grep domain.com
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 2010-08-24 12:21 domain.com

> groups newuser
newuser : newuser filetransfer

> ls -ld /srv/www/domain.com/
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 2010-08-24 12:21 /srv/www/domain.com/
```

Comment: added that output above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `ChrootDirectory` directive of OpenSSH.

This will only work if the home directory of the respective user is owned by `root:root` and is *not* world or global writable (ie. has the permission mask `0755` but not `0770`). `sshd` will issue a warning in your `auth.log` (or the destination of syslog facility AUTH) otherwise.

Comment: this is where i got a bit confused, the user has a directory inside `home` (/home/newuser) and has also been assigned the site directory using `usermod -d /srv/www/domain.com newuser` - is there something specific i can check?

Comment: The user has exactly one home directory, namely `/srv/www/domain.com`. `/home/newuser` was probably created by `useradd` when you first created the user. In the setup you've described, `/srv/www/domain.com` needs to be owned by `root:root` and must not be writable by the user. You'll have to create the needed subdirectories in `/srv/www/domain.com` yourself and `chown` them to `newuser`.

Comment: haha, i assumed i would have issues with all sub-dirs but i didnt! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The home directory is unlikely to be the issue here, if you can see the directory you want to write to, just can't write to it.

What is the output of the following commands:
`ls -al /srv/www/domain.com/ | grep public_html` (if there's a better way to that please say so)
`groups newuser`

Comment: please see above

Comment: Sorry I misread the question, the permissions for public_html look fine but you can upload there so that's to be expected :) Try this instead (sorry for the mistake):
`ls -al /srv/www/ | grep domain.com`

Comment: added above, i tried chown'ing the domain.com dir to newuser:newuser but then the sFTP stopped working completely

Comment: doesnt work i'm afraid